# Biblatex --- how to add comma before and between two names

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm currently getting:

> Surname, IN and Secondauthorsurname, FM.

I need:

> Surname, IN, and Secondauthorsurname, FM.

Searching for "comma" in the documentation is impossible, since it also hits on "command"

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author =   {First I. Last, and Second Y. Author},
  title =    {This is the article title},
  journal =  {T Journal T},
  journallongtitle =     {The Journal Title},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   50,
  pages =    {30--40}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Again it would be very helpful to know what style you use. Also, the language option is important. You might want to add a short MWE.

Comment: Thanks. Do you use `babel`/`polyglossia`? If so, what language do you load?

Comment: I added the two lines from my file which address language --- not sure why they're needed since having or not having them doesn't influence the output.

Comment: If you are using `american` you will not notice any difference, since `biblatex` defaults to `english`=`american.` But try the MWE below with `british` instead of `american` and you *will* see a difference.

Comment: Also note that you *should not* add the comma between the names, the `and` suffices. So do not write `{First I. Last, and Second Y. Author}` but `{First I. Last and Second Y. Author}`. `journallongtitle` does not seem to be a standard field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following redefinitions in your preamble.

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \finalandcomma
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{%
  \finalandcomma
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author =   {First Last and Second Author},
  title =    {This is the article title},
  journal =  {T Journal T},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   50,
  pages =    {30--40}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \finalandcomma
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{%
  \finalandcomma
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]